# How can I write a general Array to CSV file?

Tags: c#, arrays, csv

Assume that I have an Array of objects in C#, and I want to write it to a file in CSV format.
Assume that each object has a ToString() method, which is what I want to be printed.

Currently I am using this code:

```
public static void dumpArray(Array arr, string fileName)
{
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName))
    {
        foreach (Object obj in arr)
        {
             file.Write(obj.ToString()+",");
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything built in C# framework, or do you think that there is a better way?

Comment: I would use your approach as it is much better and faster to achieve just simple csv file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could change your method to use **C# Generics** and use descriptive function and variable names. This essentially results in the same behaviour except that [boxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) is avoided for value types.

```
public static void SaveArrayAsCSV<T>(T[] arrayToSave, string fileName)
{
    using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(fileName))
    {
        foreach (T item in arrayToSave)
        {
            file.Write(item + ",");
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: to do the same with jagged Arrays (assuming they only ever contain *one* level of nesting) you could use this overload **(not recommended, see below!)**:

```
public static void SaveArrayAsCSV<T>(T[][] jaggedArrayToSave, string fileName)
{
    using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(fileName))
    {
        foreach (T[] array in jaggedArrayToSave)
        {
            foreach (T item in array)
            {
               file.Write(item + ",");
            }
            file.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
```

## EDIT - Regarding duplication:

The above solution is, of course, sub-optimal in that it only works in a some specific scenarios (where we have exactly one level of nesting). Unfortunately, if refactor our code, we have to stop using generics because our input array might now contain elements of Type `T`or of Type `T[]`. Therefore, we come up with the following code, which is **the preferred solution** because, although it reintroduces boxing, is more readable, less redundant, and works for a wider range of scenarios:

```
public static void SaveArrayAsCSV(Array arrayToSave, string fileName)
{
    using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(fileName))
    {
        WriteItemsToFile(arrayToSave, file);
    }
}

private static void WriteItemsToFile(Array items, TextWriter file)
{
    foreach (object item in items)
    {
        if (item is Array)
        {
            WriteItemsToFile(item as Array, file);
            file.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }
        else file.Write(item + ",");   
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I improve this to support jagged arrays?

Comment: Row-wise, all aligned to the left, for example.

Comment: This solution doesn't account for a comma existing in one of the fields to be written, or if encapsulating in quotes, taking into account additional quotations in the fields.

Answer (score 20):

Use [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h8wc12c.aspx):

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName))
{
    file.Write(string.Join(",", arr));
}
```

Though, if you are indeed writing CSV files, you should use a CSV library such as [File Helpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/), as CSV is not as simple to get right as most people think - see [RFC 4180](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt).

---

Note that the assumption is that you have a `string[]` as the second parameter - you seem to be passing an instance of the `Array` class (which is **not** a `string[]` as you have written in your question).

---

Update:

Since you are **not** passing in a `string[]`, you should be using [File Helpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/) to ensure the objects are written correctly to a CSV.

Comment: this doesn't compile with his `Array arr` parameter, only with `string[] arr`.

Comment: I tested it and it casts arr using ToString() method. Not exactly what I want

Comment: @Andrey - Why are you using the `Array` class instead of a `string[]`?

Answer (score 2):

I believe `.csv` files can be treated as plain text files `.txt`. You can easily use:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"test.csv", string.Join(",", myDataArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are much better of using something like FileHelpers: fast and easy to use: http://www.filehelpers.com/

Answer (score 1):

[FileHelper](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/)

Not sure about built in CSV libraries as Java supports.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an extension method:

```
public static string ToCsv<T>(this IEnumerable<T> ary)
{
  return string.Join(",", ary);
}
```

and then simply call:

```
arr.ToCsv();
```

Being defined for `IEnumerable` you can also use it for `List<>`.

Comment: if only csv was this simple. this will not work thanks to newlines, and commas, in the csv.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @gburton, I have updated the answer.