# Is there a simpler way to code a array-to-CSV writer

Tags: c#, .net, string, csv

I found this implementation in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666518/how-can-i-write-a-general-array-to-csv-file)

```
public static void SaveArrayAsCSV<T>(T[] arrayToSave, string fileName)
{
    using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(fileName))
    {
        foreach (T item in arrayToSave)
        {
            file.Write(item + ",");
        }
    }
}
```

However this has some drawback, e.g. the trailing comma after the end of the array, and it missed the possibility that the item might have comma within it. I can fix this by if-else, but the code will become significantly larger. Is there a simpler way to format an array to a csv line? Possibly by using linq or more powerful method like `File.WriteAllText`?

Answer (score 7):

Please [*Stop Rolling your own CSV Parser*](http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp). Use an existing CSV parser to manipulate CSV files. Such as [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) for example. I can't believe that there are still people out there doing this the way you are doing it.

Comment: I'm trying to format to CSV, not parse it. I want to avoid using (and having to deploy) a third party library here

Comment: It's the same thing. Writing CSV is not an easy task. Believe me this will byte you if you go that route.

Comment: yet .net does not have a native writer?

Comment: You could use ADO.NET : http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2008/09/17/tip-export-to-csv-using-ado-net.aspx but I would recommend a specifically designed library for that because the `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB` driver kinda sucks.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov for some simple cases writing CSV might be quite simple task, and the using of new libraries/frameworks - not. so it is definitely depends on the task.

Comment: @ie., I really want to believe you, unfortunately I am yet to encounter a real world example where writing CSV is a simple task. I haven't yet encountered such situation in a real world application in all my career. For education purposes and POCs it could be good, but once you hit the wilderness of a real world application in production doing this by hand will byte. I just insist on this so that people writing real world applications don't do the mistake of doing this by hand. But for POCs and demonstrations joining and splitting is of course acceptable and might even work.