# c# read/store data in a file?

Tags: c#, string, file, arrays

What I want to do is actually have my program open up and set a string array so that i can use it for if commands (its used to block people) and I want to store another string in there so that it can be saved and still be used if the program restart. Can someone show me how to do this? Please and thank you :]

Comment: can you show us some code ?.

Comment: This should give you a hint: [How can I write a general Array to CSV file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666518/how-can-i-write-a-general-array-to-csv-file)

Comment: @CodeIgnoto Well the code is for my steam trade bot and I have nothing to really show since its just a feature I haven't made yet cause I never really done this type of thing in C#

Comment: If you want to store more than an array, [serialization](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1789/Object-Serialization-using-C) could be of interest to you.

Comment: @AlinaB. What I want to do is store a bunch of steamid's and then check with an if statement that the steamid is in there or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"Path here").ToArray();
```

This splits each line up into the array.

As for saving to file, [google](http://www.google.com) "saving to file in c#", you will get plenty of results and tutorials.

Comment: "Does not contain a definition for ToArray" :/

Comment: Add `Using System.Collections.Generic` to the namespace declarations of your program.

Comment: s:\-----\-----\-----.cs(69,69): Error CS1061: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'ToArray' and no extension method 'ToArray' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061)

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely better then the solution I posted first:

```
File.WriteAllLines(fileName, yourStringArray);
yourStringArray = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
```

[File.WriteAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/92e05ft3.aspx)

[File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/s2tte0y1.aspx)

***Below my first answer. Correct, but crap!***

Something like this should work for you. Don't blame me for inaccuracy, I am not wide awake yet! ;)

```
{
    string fileName = @"d:\temp\blacklist.txt";
    char seperator = ';';

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string[] users = { "Dave", "John", "Shawn" };
        //Save(users);
        users = Load();
    }

    public string[] Load()
    {
        string line;

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(this.fileName))
        {
            line = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return line.Split(seperator);
    }

    public void Save(string[] users)
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(this.fileName))
        {
            string line = string.Empty;

            foreach (string user in users)
            {
                line += string.Format("{0}{1}", user, seperator);
            }

            sw.WriteLine(line);
            sw.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there not a simpler way? Lol this seems like a lot :P

Comment: Yeah my first answer was ... crap. See improved answer!

Comment: Cool! Looks like I got it to work, but the only thing is i cant seem to figure out how to just add a line and not erase the whole document.. :P

Comment: I guess [File.AppendAllLines Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd383691.aspx)